# Blogdown - How to use OSMap Tiles in Hugo Academic

Tags: openstreetmap, hugo, blogdown

I'm wondering if anyone knows how to change the OS Map tiles using the Hugo Academic theme in Blogdown, as the contact map uses Leaflet so it should be possible to change the tile URL, but I just can't find where that is located. The only method of changing the map type I have found are the standard options available in `config/_default/params.toml`, but I can't figure out where they are directing instructions to.

Thanks,

**Edit:**

This is the tile server I was hoping on using.

`http://a.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/${z}/${x}/${y}.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The openstreetmap tiles are defined here:

https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic/blob/master/assets/js/academic.js#L276

Around those lines you'll see some examples for other map tile providers as well.

Tell us the provider you want to use so that we can show you a code example for intergrating that one.

Edit: To use the HOT style by the openstreetmap.fr tile provider add the following between the lines 274 and 275 in the academic.js:

`} else if(map_provider == 4) {
          L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 19,
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
          }).addTo(map);
        }`

and in your params.toml on line 262 set `engine = 4`.

Comment: Thank you. I have found the `academic.js` file and edited my question to include the tile server

Comment: I've updated the answer to include instructions for using the HOT tiles from openstreetmap.fr in the HUGO academic theme.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately when I added that, it returned a blank map - am I correct in assuming that it's because it is not possible to use this particular tile and I should use a different one?

Comment: Those tiles should be useable. Do you see any Javascript errors in your console?

Comment: My bad - it just needed to be restarted and it's all working well. Thanks for your help